# check for multiple role in route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In route page I want to check the role is either Department Head
 or Service Line Head.How to check both in router

```
Route::get ('view-records', [ 
    'uses' => 'assetApprovalController@assetRequestDetails',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => [ 
            'Department Head' //want to check here
       ] 
     ]
);
```

resolved by adding 'Department Head,Service Line Head' in role as

```
Route::get ('view-records', [ 
    'uses' => 'assetApprovalController@assetRequestDetails',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => [ 
            'Department Head,Service Line Head' //added here
       ] 
     ]
);
```

Comment: You need to check this inside your Roles Middleware simple get the route action

Comment: you can check with middleware or by checking manually in the route like,
`if(Auth::user()->role=='Department Head'){ // pass your routes here acording to Department Head role } else {// pass your routes here acording to Department Head another role }`

Comment: how to check in route @Rits

Comment: or if you have multiple roles you can go with if() else if() and so on

Comment: but make sure you need one column in user schema of role.
`Auth::user()->role` this statement can get your role, here `role` is a column you can change it according to your column name

Answer (score 1):

you can send parameters to you middlware like this `'middleware' => 'roles:Department_Head'` to check the user's role but it's only allow you to send only one parameter. So what you can do is that change your middleware to receive the parameter as an array by putting `...` to your parameter like this  `...$role` in your middleware then you can do `'middleware' => 'roles:Department_Head,Admin,User'`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next , ...$Userrole)
{
   if (in_array(auth()->user()->role ,$Userroles)) {
      return $next($request);
   }

   return redirect('/');
}
```